# Memory Utilization of any Spark Job

Tags: apache-spark, memory-management

I have developed an algorithm in Spark and I need to report the memory consumption of my algorithm throughout its execution for different input data size. Specifically, I require the peak memory utilization and peak IO usage of my Spark job during its execution for each node or for a each executor. My questions are

1. Spark UI provides RDD size in the storage tab. Will adding all RDD sizes be sufficient for the memory consumption or I have to look any other things.
2. If I have to compare mine with other algorithms, how to check the memory consumption. Because in that case I won't have access the codes.
3. How to calculate peak IO usage. Does Shuffle read/write will help in this case.

Comment: Did you ever got the answer? I am looking for same info.

Comment: Looking for similar thing where memory utilization can be monitored and fine tuned...

Comment: Me too, I want to see execution memory. Storage memory can be normally seen in SparkUI executors tab as Storage Memory.

Comment: I have heard about Ganglia Monitoring System which can be found on http://ganglia.info/. However, I haven't used it yet. Hope that helps.